# Checkbox check all is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a form field where I have two fields one containing countries and other containing memberships and both have check boxes. The problem is that with the code I am using to Select All the countries (check/uncheck all the check boxes for countries) also checks or unchecks the memberships field. I want to differentiate between the two so that I only check countries and not the check boxes in the membership field.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$("#checkCountries").click(function(){
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

EDIT: HTML PART

```
<tr>
   <th>Target Memberships</th>
   <td>
      <div class="target-memberships col-sm-8">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="memberships[]" checked> Standard<br>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="memberships[]" checked> Premium<br>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="memberships[]" checked> Elite<br>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>Target Countries</th>
   <td>
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkCountries" checked> Select All<br>
       <div class="target-countries col-sm-8">
         <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country" value="Afghanistan" checked> Afghanistan<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country" value="Albania" checked> Albania<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country" value="Algeria" checked> Algeria<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country" value="American Samoa" checked> American Samoa<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country" value="Andorra" checked> Andorra<br>
         <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country" value="Angola" checked> Angola<br>
       </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Here, `input:checkbox` is making the code to work on all the checkboxes in the page. I think I need to change this to make it work specifically for that particular field (countries) only. Please help.

Comment: Build a snippet that shows this code working / not working, please.  You can either build one in the question (click the snippet button), or using [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Show your relevant `HTML`.

Comment: @cale_b I have updated HTML part.. please have a look..

Comment: @Ivan86 I have updated HTML part.. please have a look..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your HTML is like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkCountries" checked="checked"> Select All<br>
<div class="target-countries col-sm-8">
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-1" value="Afghanistan" checked="checked" /> Afghanistan<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-2" value="Albania"  checked="checked" /> Albania<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-3" value="Algeria"  checked="checked" /> Algeria<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-4" value="American Samoa" checked="checked" /> American Samoa<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-5" value="Andorra"  checked="checked" /> Andorra<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-6" value="Angola"  checked="checked" /> Angola<br>
 </div>
```

In HTML, each `id` must be unique. The `name` can be the same as you have to define the array: `country[]`, but the `id` must be unique to each element. Since `input` has no closing tag, it is best to add that to the end of the tag, `<input type="checkbox" />` for example.

You can use this:

```
$("#checkCountries").click(function(){
  $(".target-countries input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

This targets the Class selector `target-countries` and the `input` elements within that are of a type `checkbox`. It will then set the property `checked` to match the value of the current checkbox.

Working Snippet:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#checkCountries").click(function() {
    $(".target-countries input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", $(this).prop("checked"));
  });
});
```

```css
.target-countries {
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkCountries" checked="checked"> Select All<br>
<div class="target-countries col-sm-8">
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-1" value="Afghanistan" checked="checked" /> Afghanistan<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-2" value="Albania" checked="checked" /> Albania<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-3" value="Algeria" checked="checked" /> Algeria<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-4" value="American Samoa" checked="checked" /> American Samoa<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-5" value="Andorra" checked="checked" /> Andorra<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" id="country-6" value="Angola" checked="checked" /> Angola<br>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: ohh crap.. that was pretty easy.... as soon as I saw the updated answer I cursed myself for not getting it.. that was too simple... however I am still using `$('.target-countries input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);` instead of whole change I just added the class.. working.. thanks :)

Comment: and yes I am not using that ID field as of now so no worry for making it unique at the moment :)

Comment: @Kanishk I suspect you would have found it if you searched SO or Google. It was simple, so I felt like answering it instead of voting to close it. Always SEARCH before asking.

Comment: I searched for the same but I found results which did not match what I searched for. It takes a lot of time asking a question here and waiting for the answer. So its a natural instinct that I will search on Google or SO before I decide to finally create my own. I always consider asking the question as the last option and since before yesterday I did not found a exactly related question/answer to my problem so my question and your answer will help others to get the solution if they get into the same situation in future. I really appreciate you took time answering rather than voting for close.